# Difference between int CompareTo method and ordinary If condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, comparison

I have tried the comparison for two integer values by using two types

**Type 1 :**

```
 int val1 = 1;
 int val2 = 2;

var returnValue = val1.CompareTo(val2);//-1 for First int is smaller.
varreturnValue = val2.CompareTo(val1);// 1 for First int is larger
varreturnValue = val1.CompareTo(val1);//0 for Ints are equal.

If(varreturnValue ==1)
 {
    //Success
 }
 else
 {
   //Failure 
 }
```

**Type 2:**

```
 int val1 = 1;
 int val2 = 2;

if (val1 < val2)
{
    //return -1 //Failure
}
else if (val2 < val1)
{
    //return 2 //Success 
}
else
{
    // return 0  // Same 
}
```

- What is the difference these methods?

  - Which one(type)  is better for standard coding .. ?
  - Any difference for performance in the types ?

Comment: For your use case - there's no real difference. But `CompareTo` may be used via interface, `IComparable<T>`, which is useful when you have a constrained generic type and want do to comparisons (hint: ordered collections, e.g. binary trees etc.). `<` or `>` wouldn't work then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I take a peek at the internals of int's `CompareTo()` method (using ReSharper), I see this:

```
public int CompareTo(int value)
{
  if (this < value)
    return -1;
  return this > value ? 1 : 0;
}
```

So it would appear, in the case of an int anyway, that the `CompareTo()` function is doing exactly what your second example does.

If we remove the ternary operator, it looks identical to your example:

```
public int CompareTo(int value)
{
  if (this < value)
    return -1;

  if (this > value)
    return -1;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But here we need another one condition for return value of comparto method. Is it good?

Comment: I mean . If we used the comparto method, Then we need to check condition for -1 or 1 or 0 for find big and less values .

Comment: +1 for shown the method , Nice one ! Thanks for your suggestion ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the `CompareTo` method is good in case you need to ***separate*** the logic that checks for equality and another logic that uses the result from the comparison. In your example, when you do your code like:

```
int val1 = 1;
 int val2 = 2;

if (val1 < val2)
{
    //return -1 //Failure
}
else if (val2 < val1)
{
    //return 2 //Success 
}
else
{
    // return 0  // Same 
}
```

You cannot ***return*** to another function the ***comparison result***. Here is the code extracted from msdn:

```
enum Comparison {
   LessThan=-1, Equal=0, GreaterThan=1};

public class ValueComparison
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      int mainValue = 16325;
      int zeroValue = 0;
      int negativeValue = -1934;
      int positiveValue = 903624;
      int sameValue = 16325;

      Console.WriteLine("Comparing {0} and {1}: {2} ({3}).",  
                        mainValue, zeroValue, 
                        mainValue.CompareTo(zeroValue), 
                        (Comparison) mainValue.CompareTo(zeroValue));
    }
}
```

In this case, the comparison result is represented as an enum and can be ***passed*** between functions.

Another case is you could even ***serialize*** the comparison result over the wire as a numeric value (-1,0,1) (return value of an ajax call, for example)

There may be not much thing to do with numeric comparison like this, but as noted by  Patryk Ćwiek in his comment. `CompareTo` may be used via interface, which can be ***implemented*** by other datatypes including your custom ones.

Comment: Yup. You is good . But console window show 1 and -1. we need to show  another condition for greater value. So is good?

Comment: @Ramesh Rajendran: See my updated answer. This is helpful when you implement comparison for your custom datatypes and use the same interface for comparison.